# Check whether a type is a template specialization or not

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

Given an **arbitrary template class/struct**, just like:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {};
```

I would like to perform a [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) fashion check *(let's name it is_A)* to determine whether an **arbitrary** type is a **specialization of A** or not, just like:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct is_A: std::integral_constant<bool, /* perform the check here */ > {};

constexpr bool test0 = is_A< A<int> >::value // true
constexpr bool test1 = is_A< A<float> >::value // true
constexpr bool test2 = is_A< int >::value // false
constexpr bool test2 = is_A< float >::value // false
```

**How is that possible?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specialize for `A<T>`:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_A : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct is_A<A<T>> : std::true_type { };
```